# Types in destructured value of object in function-like parameter's function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, object-destruction

So, we have some function:

```
const someVal = func(customObject => {console.log(customObject.data.users)});
```

We can rewrite this function with object-destruction syntax to make it more pretty and laconic for *users* value:

```
const someVal = func(({ data: { users } = {}) => {console.log(users)});
```

Now imagine, that *users* value must be described by some typescript interface.

How it should be done inline?

Like this?

```
 const someVal = func(({ data: { users } = {} : { data: { users : UserInterface }) => {console.log(users)});
```

UPD. *data* is generic value variable

Answer (score 0):

You could do it inline but it can get quite messy. I generally prefer to define types for better readability:

```
type SomeValInput = {
  data: {
    users?: UserInterface;
  };
};
type SomeVal = (data: SomeValInput) => void;
const someVal: SomeVal = ({ data: { users } }) => console.log(users || {});
```

I didn't include the default value in the destructuring, as I've had trouble with using that in combination with typescript in the past.

Comment: Imagine, that you have n usages of __func__ function. You would create n analogues of __SomeValInput__  type? (keys in data object could vary). In this case, creating n __SomeValInput__ types would be messy too, i think.

Comment: Ahh maybe I misread -- if you're talking about typing 1 function for multiple types of inputs, then you may want to overload the type signature -- https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading

In general, yes I recommend creating distinct types for different types of data -- one of the side benefits of TS that I've found is clearer documentation-as-code. But without understanding what data you're working with it's tough to say